# DHT22 возвращает неверные показания при отрицательной температуре

Tags: arduino, железо

Нижеследующий код читает показания DHT22 на заданном параметром пине. При опущении температуры ниже 0 °C данный код возвращает неадекватные значения в диапазоне от -3200 до -3300 (чаще всего значения колеблются около -3275). При использовании [библиотеки](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library) значения также неверны. Код используется [отсюда](http://arduino.ru/forum/apparatnye-voprosy/chitaem-pokazaniya-dht-bez-biblioteki).

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Firmata.h>


uint64_t readingTime;


void DHTt(const uint8_t pin) {
    if ((millis() - readingTime) > 2000) {
        unsigned char receivedDHTData[5];
        float temperature, humidity;

        #define DHT_PORT  PORTD 
        #define DHT_DDR   DDRD
        #define DHT_PIN   PIND
        #define DHT_BIT   pin  
        int count = 32;
        unsigned char i,j;
        

        ReLoad:                           //метка для ошибок
        //=============MCU send START
        DHT_DDR|=(1<<DHT_BIT);            //выход
        DHT_PORT&=~(1<<DHT_BIT);          //низкий уровень, подтягиваем линию, разбудим датчик
        delay(18);                        //18 мс по условиям документации.
        DHT_PORT|=(1<<DHT_BIT);           //отпускаем линию
        DHT_DDR&=~(1<<DHT_BIT);           //пин как выход
        

        //============= инциализация DHT
        delayMicroseconds(50);            //задержка по условию
        if (DHT_PIN&(1<<DHT_BIT)) {       //датчик должен ответить 0
            if (count != 0) {
                goto ReLoad;
                count--;
            } else {
                Firmata.sendString("ERR;DHTt;INIT");
                return;
            }
        }

        delayMicroseconds(80);
        if (!(DHT_PIN&(1<<DHT_BIT))) {    //по истечению 80 мкс, датчик должен отпустить шину 
            if (count != 0) {
                goto ReLoad;
                count--;
            } else {
                Firmata.sendString("ERR;DHTt;BHVR");
                return;
            }
        }
        

        //===============Приём 40 бит данных
        while (DHT_PIN&(1<<DHT_BIT));            //ждем пока на шине появится 1  
        for (j=0; j<5; j++) {                    //цикл для 0-4 байт
            receivedDHTData[j]=0;
            for(i=0; i<8; i++) {                 //приём битов и укладка их в байты
                while (!(DHT_PIN&(1<<DHT_BIT))); //ждем когда датчик отпустит шину
                delayMicroseconds(30);           //задержка высокого уровня при 0 30 мкс
                if (DHT_PIN&(1<<DHT_BIT))        //если по истечению времени сигнал на линии высокий, значит передается 1
                    receivedDHTData[j]|=1<<(7-i);           //тогда i-й бит устанавливаем 1
                while (DHT_PIN&(1<<DHT_BIT));    //ждем окончание 1 
                }
            }


        if ((unsigned char)(receivedDHTData[0] + receivedDHTData[1] + 
            receivedDHTData[2] + receivedDHTData[3])!=receivedDHTData[4]) { //checksum
            Firmata.sendString("ERR;DHTt;CHSM");
            return;
        }

        temperature = (receivedDHTData [3]*0.1) + ((receivedDHTData [2] & 0b01111111)*25.6); //нюанс расчета температуры для DHT22
        if (receivedDHTData [2] & 0b10000000)  temperature*= -1;            //если отрицательная температура
        humidity = (receivedDHTData [1]*0.1) + (receivedDHTData [0]*25.6);                //нюанс расчета влажности для DHT22
        
        char result[32], catres[8];
        readingTime = millis();
        strcpy(result, "OK;DHTt;");

        dtostrf(temperature, 5, 2, catres);
        strcat(result, catres);
        strcat(result, ";");

        dtostrf(humidity, 5, 2, catres);
        strcat(result, catres);

        Firmata.sendString(result);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите, мб вот это вам поможет - https://github.com/esphome/issues/issues/1744#issuecomment-864331848

Comment: Этот же вопрос на Arduino SE: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/86448/dht22-sensor-reading-code-interpretes-negative-values-weirdly-common-problem